# Incompatibility of apply in dask and pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dask

A sample of the `triggers` column in my **Dask dataframe** looks like the following:

```
0    [Total Traffic, DNS, UDP]
1                    [TCP RST]
2              [Total Traffic]
3                 [IP Private]
4                       [ICMP]
Name: triggers, dtype: object
```

I wish to create a one hot encoded version of the above arrays (putting a `1` against the `DNS` column in row 1 for example) by doing the following. `pop_triggers` contains all possible values of `triggers`.

```
for trig in pop_triggers:
    df[trig] = df.triggers.apply(lambda x: 1 if trig in x else 0)
```

However, the `Total Traffic`, `DNS` etc. columns all contain the value 0 and not 1 for the relevant value. When I copy it into a pandas dataframe and do the same operation, they get the expected value.

```
a = df[[ 'Total Traffic', 'UDP', 'NTP Amplification', 'triggers', 'ICMP']].head()
for trig in pop_triggers:
    a[trig] = a.triggers.apply(lambda x: 1 if trig in x else 0)
```

What am I missing here? Is it because dask is lazy that somehow it's not filling in the values as expected?

**Edit 1:**
I investigated some places where the flag was set in the first place (which turned out to be far less than I expected, and got some really weird results. See below:

```
df2 = df[df['Total Traffic']==1]
df2[['triggers']+pop_triggers].head()
```

output:

```
        triggers    Total Traffic   UDP DNS
9380    [ICMP, IP null, IP Private, TCP null, TCP SYN,...   1   1   1
9388    [ICMP, IP null, IP Private, TCP null, TCP SYN,...   1   1   1
19714   [ICMP, IP null, IP Private, UDP, NTP Amplifica...   1   1   1
21556   [IP null]   1   1   1
21557   [IP null]   1   1   1
```

**possible bug maybe?**

**Edit 2:**
Minimal working example:

```
triggers = [['Total Traffic', 'DNS', 'UDP'],['TCP RST'],['Total Traffic'],['IP Private'],['ICMP']]*10
df2 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'triggers':triggers}), npartitions=16)
pop_triggers= ['Total Traffic', 'UDP', 'DNS', 'TCP SYN', 'TCP null', 'ICMP']
for trig in pop_triggers:
    df2[trig] = df2.triggers.apply(lambda x: 1 if trig in x else 0)
df2.head()
```

Output:

```
triggers    Total Traffic   UDP DNS TCP SYN TCP null    ICMP
0   [Total Traffic, DNS, UDP]   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   [TCP RST]   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   [Total Traffic] 0   0   0   0   0   0
3   [IP Private]    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Note:** I am far more concerned about the Dask side of things and not Pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience `apply` in `dask` works much better with explicit [`metadata`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#metadata). There are some functionality that let `dask` attempt to guess the `metadata` but I found it slow and not always reliable. Also the guidance is to specify `meta`.

Another point in my experience is that `assign` works better than `df[col] = ...`. Not sure if it's a bug, a limitation or a misuse on my side (I researched that a while ago and I don't think it's a bug).

**EDIT:** The first pattern doesn't work, the `trig` value used for previous columns in the loop seems to be updated with later values so at compute time, this gives only the result of the last value for all columns!

It's not a bug but the combination of not computing immediately while the lambda result of the delayed computation on the closure which is not evaluated yet. See [this discussion](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2774) for why it doesn't work.

<s>My pattern for you would then be:</s>

```
cols = {}
for trig in pop_triggers:
    meta = (trig, int)
    cols[trig] = df.triggers.apply(lambda x: 1 if trig in x else 0, meta=meta)
df = df.assign(**cols)
```

**CORRECT PATTERN:**

(sorry didn't test previously as I run the same pattern except I don't use the looping value in the applied function so didn't face that behavior)

```
cols = {}

for trig in pop_triggers:
    meta = (trig, int)

    def fn(x, t):
        return 1 if t in x else 0

    cols[trig] = ddf.triggers.apply(fn, args=(trig,), meta=meta)
ddf = ddf.assign(**cols)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm afraid this didn't work. Try checking `df.head()`.

Comment: so I see what's going on, the last serie computed from the loop get assigned to all columns, looks at mutability issue. Which is weird because I have almost the exact same piece of code that have been using for several weeks now... Actually, it feels like the `trig` in the `lambda` is kept mutable and so the last value is used when computing all columns.

Comment: Answer updated with a working version. It'd be worthwhile to check with the devs whether this is expected behavior (in which case I don't think docs highlight the issue) or a bug